# Cannot set Full Control permission for folder

Tags: c#, acl, ntfs

I'm trying to add the `Full Control` permission (for a NT service account) to a folder through C#. However, the permission is not set, what I am missing here?

```
var directoryInfo = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\Test");
var directorySecurity = directoryInfo.GetAccessControl();

directorySecurity.AddAccessRule(new FileSystemAccessRule("NT Service\\FileMoverService",
    FileSystemRights.FullControl, AccessControlType.Allow));

directoryInfo.SetAccessControl(directorySecurity);
```

[image: folder permissions]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to specify the inheritance flags:

```
directorySecurity.AddAccessRule(new FileSystemAccessRule(@"NT Service\FileMoverService",
    FileSystemRights.FullControl,
    InheritanceFlags.ContainerInherit | InheritanceFlags.ObjectInherit,
    PropagationFlags.None,
    AccessControlType.Allow));
```

Answer (score 3):

The method `GrantFullControl` can be used to set the `Full Control` permission for a given directory and user.

```
private static void GrantFullControl(string directoryPath, string username)
{
    if (!Directory.Exists(directoryPath))
        return;

    var directorySecurity = Directory.GetAccessControl(directoryPath);
    directorySecurity.AddAccessRule(new FileSystemAccessRule(username, FileSystemRights.FullControl,
        InheritanceFlags.ContainerInherit | InheritanceFlags.ObjectInherit, PropagationFlags.None,
        AccessControlType.Allow));

    Directory.SetAccessControl(directoryPath, directorySecurity);
}
```

Just call the method as shown below.

```
GrantFullControl(@"C:\Test", @"NT Service\FileMoverService");
```